# First Week of Month in Power BI

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop, m

I have a date table with Day and Date columns in Power BI.
I would like to add a column which tells me if that week includes the first day of month.
For example when 1st of November is Friday, then it returns a "Yes" for that week.
Therefore, the column "IsFirstWeekOfMonth" shows "Yes" for the working days of a week which has 1st day of month.
Something like below:

[image]

Would you please let me know how I can do this in Power BI (M or DAX). Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a calculated column with the following logic, also checking if is or not a weekend day (for Saturdays and Sundays):

```
IsFistWeekOfMonth = IF(OR(WEEKDAY('Table'[Date].[Date],2)==6,WEEKDAY('Table'[Date].[Date],2)==7),"No",IF(AND(OR(WEEKNUM(DATE('Table'[Date].[Year],'Table'[Date].[MonthNo],1))==WEEKNUM('Table'[Date].[Date],2),WEEKNUM(DATE('Table'[Date].[Year],'Table'[Date].[MonthNo]+1,1))==WEEKNUM('Table'[Date].[Date],2)),WEEKDAY(DATE('Table'[Date].[Year],'Table'[Date].[MonthNo],1),2)IN{1,2,3,4,5}),"Yes","No"))
```

Please tell me if this can help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. This is helpful indeed but not 100%. This will give a Yes for the week but only starting from the 1st day of the month. For example for the data in the question sample above, with your calculated column we will have yes only for Friday 01/11/2019 and Sat 02/11/2019 and Sun 03/11/2019. What I need is the YES starting from Monday 28/10/2019. I mean the whole week needs to have a YES if the 1st day of month is there. BUT thank you very much anyways. I keep thinking and will let you know if I find a solution.

Comment: The only solution that comes to my mind is : If the 1st day of month is Monday, then add "YES" to that day and all four days after. or if the 1st day of month is Tuesday, then add "YES" to that day and one day before and all three days after.  or if the 1st day of month is Wednesday, then add "YES" to that day and two days  before and two days after and etc..  Is it possible to write a code such that?

Comment: Sorry, don´t look in detail for your question. Edited the formula. If this is want you really want, now hope so, please give me some feedback :)

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot. This gives completely correct outcome for when the 1st day of month is in the working days, and it will return "YES" from Mon to Fri! That is amazing! But there is only one issue. With your calculated column when the 1st of month is Saturday it returns the week before as "YES" and when the 1st of month is Sunday it returns the week after as "YES". Could we tell the if condition to ignore when first of month is Sat or Sun and return "NO" for all the weeks before and after? we only need YES when the first day of month is in the working days and not in the weekends. Thanks alot

Comment: Nice to help you, your suggestion is also posible but this is more "elegant" in terms of query. Related to your last question, changed again the calculated column. If this is the answer you espect and you can give the answer as correct will be great also, thanks :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :) I deleted the weekend condition from the question so that your previous code was a correct answer. Would you please delete the weekend condition from your code in the answer, so that we have the previous one from yesterday. Thanks one more time indeed and all the best.